# PHP Style Question

Tags: php, xml, coding-style

My preexisting application that I'm trying to edit  uses PHP / Javascript / XML and stylesheets to accomplih a big multilevel dropdown menu.  The php reads each element of the xml file, based on what it is (opening or closing tag) writes html.

The problem is this all happens AFTER the  tags and I need to style based on the looping level of the XML  I know how to set the styles based on the loop, but I dont know how to print them because I have already printed the  tags

The browser would have renederd them already

Does anyoen know how I can fix this?

PS...i cant use inline stlyes for this because the javascript and the html are linked...its gotta be external or local between style tags.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have? It may help in getting a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to add another node in the XML for holding the class info and then using that in the loop when constructing the menu?  Probably easiest would be to find where it starts to write the menu, usually a `<ul>` or whatever, and add a class or id there for the whole menu, and then do like

```
ul.class ul ul li
{
     background-color:#FFFF00;
}
```

in the style sheet for how ever many child levels of the menu there are (ul.class ul ul li would be 2 child levels down)

Comment: Unfortunatly that wont work...the reason being is that it is the PHP parser which counts the nested levels of UL tags.....and based on that nested level it wites stlyes.....all the stlyes have to be unique....i cant define them ahead of time...so if theres 24 nested menus there will be 24 style declorations....all of which i have generated....problem is the style tags are closed...i have nowhere to insert them. unfortunatly i cant use inlien stles either.

Comment: @Craig, if you can't use inline styles and you can't edit any style tags (external or internal) then you should maybe rethink this whole endeavor of trying to style this output.

Comment: Id love to...but this code wasnt written by me originally....its taken from open sourse and repurposed....im so close to the end....i just need a way to read during content and write styles afterwards....or edit the order which the flow of the website is read....in other words   do PHP then create styles....does this make sense?

Comment: I was able to get it working with inline styles.  I made a mistake when trying it the first time....sorry for wasting all your time...but thanks for the quick responses